# dynamic imports/exports components in vue.js with .ts files

Tags: typescript, vue.js, import, export, vue-composition-api

In Vue.js project, i have a file services.ts which contains code

```
export { default as UserService } from "@/views/user/services/UserService";
export { default as LoginHistoryService } from "@/views/user/services/LoginHistoryService";
export { default as PermissionGroupService } from "@/views/permission-group/services/PermissionGroupService";
export { default as PermissionService } from "@/views/permission/services/PermissionService";
export { default as ManufacturerService } from "@/views/manufacturer/services/ManufacturerService";
export { default as AdminGroupService } from "@/views/admin-group/services/AdminGroupService";
```

When i write

```
import { ManufacturerService } from "@/api/imports/services";
```

in some other file, i want to load just ManufacturerService, but when i check Network tab on inspect page, i can see that other services are also loaded, which can slow down my app. How can i import just ManufacturerService, without others?

with .vue files, there is dynamic export with

```
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";
```

, but i need it for .ts files also where ManufacturerService is class in typescript.

Thanks in advance,

Nikola

i really couldnt find any solution